# How do I sort html tables in knockout using a Breeze navigation property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, breeze

I am using Breeze.js for handing my data model off to Knockout.js in a fairly straightforward view model handling an adapter library.  I have sorting tables on my entity properties using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and this knockout binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var asc = false;
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

        element.onclick = function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var prop = value.prop;
            var data = value.arr;

            asc = !asc;
            if (asc) {
                data.sort(function (left, right) {
                    return left[prop]() === right[prop]() ? 0 : left[prop]() < right[prop]() ? -1 : 1;
                });
            } else {
                data.sort(function (left, right) {
                    return left[prop]() === right[prop]() ? 0 : left[prop]() > right[prop]() ? -1 : 1;
                });
            }
        };
    }
};
```

I am expanding the navigation property in my Breeze data service, it is data-binding the data to the table just fine.

```
em.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from('SpecificAdapters').expand('Adapter'));
```

Accessing specific data in my EF from js would be: `specificAdapters()[0].Adapter().BoardName`.  Using html like this:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-bind="sort: {arr: specificAdapters, prop: 'Adapter().BoardName'}">Board Name</th>
            <th data-bind="sort: {arr: specificAdapters, prop: 'PbaNumber'}">Pba Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: specificAdapters">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Adapter().BoardName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: PbaNumber"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am seeing both the Board Name and PBA Number columns populate without error.  The PBA Number column sorts both directions.  I get an error, obviously, using the Board Name column for sorting.

*The question is, how do I make this work?*

I don't quite understand the binding handler code well enough to know what to change to make this work for either case.  My other solution I do understand would involve extending the Entity in Breeze like

```
var store = em.metadataStore;
var SpecificAdapter = function () { this.BoardName = ko.observable(''); };
store.registerEntityTypeCtor('SpecificAdapter', SpecificAdapter);
```

Then running a loop after the query executes to remap the Board Name into the other entity.  That seems like a kludge though and would have to be executed a lot throughout my app, where a fix to the binding handler would be the best solution.

**Thanks to @awexfwex for the answer**

I had to adjust the code a bit: `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` is current access to unwrapping, and the `leftProp[propNestings[i]]` actually translates a nested and *not yet unwrapped* property, which will show up like `"Adapter()"`.  So you have to remove the `()` before using it to index your array.

Final code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var asc = false;
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

        element.onclick = function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var prop = value.prop;
            var data = value.arr;

            var propNestings = prop.split(".");
            var propNestingsCount = propNestings.length;

            asc = !asc;
            if (asc) {
                data.sort(function (left, right) {
                    var leftProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(left);
                    var rightProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(right);
                    for (var i = 0; i < propNestingsCount; i++) {
                        leftProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(leftProp[propNestings[i].replace('()', '')]);
                        rightProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(rightProp[propNestings[i].replace('()', '')]);
                    }
                    return leftProp === rightProp ? 0 : leftProp < rightProp ? -1 : 1;
                });
            } else {
                data.sort(function (left, right) {
                    var leftProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(left);
                    var rightProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(right);
                    for (var i = 0; i < propNestingsCount; i++) {
                        leftProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(leftProp[propNestings[i].replace('()', '')]);
                        rightProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(rightProp[propNestings[i].replace('()', '')]);
                    }
                    return leftProp === rightProp ? 0 : leftProp > rightProp ? -1 : 1;
                });
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sorting function, it's assuming the sort property is just a named property of a knockout observable. You could try recursively unwrapping them, something like (untested):

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.sort = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var asc = false;
        element.style.cursor = 'pointer';

        element.onclick = function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var prop = value.prop;
            var data = value.arr;

            var propNestings = prop.split(".");
            var propNestingsCount = propNestings.length;

            asc = !asc;
            if (asc) {
                data.sort(function (left, right) {
                    var leftProp = ko.unwrapObservable(left);
                    var rightProp = ko.unwrapObservable(right);
                    for (var i = 0; i < propNestingsCount; i++) {
                        leftProp = ko.unwrapObservable(leftProp[propNestings[i]]);
                        rightProp = ko.unwrapObservable(rightProp[propNestings[i]]);
                    }
                    return leftProp === rightProp ? 0 : leftProp < rightProp ? -1 : 1;
                });
            } else {
                data.sort(function (left, right) {
                    var leftProp = ko.unwrapObservable(left);
                    var rightProp = ko.unwrapObservable(right);
                    for (var i = 0; i < propNestingsCount; i++) {
                        leftProp = ko.unwrapObservable(leftProp[propNestings[i]]);
                        rightProp = ko.unwrapObservable(rightProp[propNestings[i]]);
                    }
                    return leftProp === rightProp ? 0 : leftProp > rightProp ? -1 : 1;
                });
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, it is assuming the named property, I am just fairly new to JS so some of what you just listed occurred to me but I didn't have any idea how to go about it.  Thanks for this, I will implement this tonight and get back to you.

Comment: This worked, I am adding the finished/tested code to the question. Also, `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` is the correct area to access current knockout.  I also had to remove the "()" from the `leftProp` and `rightProp` when using them as an array index.